# $http in a service returns $$state object

Tags: angularjs

I m using following code. I am reading a json file name is "hassan.json". If i read this file in controller through $http everything works fine. but i want to use the data that i read from file, again and again in different controller so i made a service for this. but **in service when i read data from that json file through $http.get()** and in return when i call that service method in my controller and console.log(data) **it returns me this in console   "e {$$state: object}."**

*this is **Controller**:*

```
app.controller('showdata', function($scope, service){
    $scope.mydata = service.getData().then(function(user){
       $scope.mydata = (user.data);
       console.log(($scope.mydata));
     });

});
```

*this is **service** i'm using:*

```
app.service('service', function($http, $q){
  var outData;
  this.getData = function() {
     if (this.outData === undefined) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     $http.get('jsons/hassan.json')
        .then(function(data){
          this.outData = data;
          deferred.resolve(data);
        },
        function(err) {
          deferred.reject(err);
        });
     return deferred.promise;
    }
    else {
        return this.outData;
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: As your call is async, you should have console.log after resolved i.e.  `$scope.mydata = service.getData().then(function(user){
       $scope.mydata = (user.data);   console.log(($scope.mydata));
     });
`

Comment: can u please modify my code and then comment it

Comment: Modified your original source. Please test with modified source in your controller

Answer (score 3):

`$http` by itself is a promise, so there is no need in `$q`, try to rewrite your code using `$http`'s `cache`:

```
app.controller('showdata', function($scope, service){
  service.getData().then(function(user) {
    // no need to call user.data, service handles this
    $scope.mydata = user;
    console.log($scope.mydata);
  }).catch(function (err) {
    // handle errors here if needed
  });
});
```

and

```
app.service('service', function($http){
  this.getData = function() {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'jsons/hassan.json',
      // cache will ensure calling ajax only once
      cache: true
    }).then(function (data) {
      // this will ensure that we get clear data in our service response
      return data.data;
    });
  };
}});
```

Comment: brother u are calling getData method in controlller that is not declared anywhere in service  ---> service.getData is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Change the controller as below:

```
app.controller('showdata', function($scope, service){
    service.getData().then(function(user){
       $scope.mydata = (user.data);
       console.log(($scope.mydata));
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is different between `$http.get().then()` and `$http.get().success()`.
Change your code to this:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.get('jsons/hassan.json')
    .success(function(data){
      this.outData = data;
      deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    });
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: `$http.get().success()` and `error()` are deprecated (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b54a39e2029005e0572fbd2ac0e8f6a4e5d69014), you should use `then()` instead

Comment: @Andriy in v1.6.0 !!  I'm sure He is not using v1.6.0 !

Comment: @MeTe-30, sorry for down voting, 1) Angular js version was not mentioned, 2) absolutely redundant use of `$q` service